# How do the pointers work in the Linked List?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I've just learned the Linked List reverse function but don't understand it not enough I think.
The first, second, temp variables are Pointers right? And they are going to change within the while loop, am i right? What I badly understand how does it reverse it. I went through it multiple times with the debugger but still dont understand how the Pointers work here and how it changes its next value.
Here is the Linked List:

```
class LinkedList {
        constructor(value) {
            this.head = {
                value: value,
                next: null
            };
            this.tail = this.head;
            this.length = 1;
        }
        append(value) {
          const newNode = {
            value: value,
            next: null
          }
          this.tail.next = newNode;
          this.tail = newNode;
          this.length++;
          return this;
        }
        printList() {
          const array = [];
          let currentNode = this.head;
          while(currentNode !== null){
              array.push(currentNode.value)
              currentNode = currentNode.next
          }
          return array;
        }
        reverse() {
          if (!this.head.next) {
            return this.head;
          }
          var first = this.head; // 1
          this.tail = this.head; 
          var second = first.next; // 2
          while(second) { // Runs 2 times
            const temp = second.next; // 3
            second.next = first; // 3 => 1
            first = second; // 1 => 2
            second = temp;  2 => 3
          }
      
          this.head.next = null;
          this.head = first;
          return this;
        }
    }
    
    let myLinkedList = new LinkedList(1);
    myLinkedList.append(2)
    myLinkedList.append(3)
    myLinkedList.reverse()
```

I would highly appreciate if you could explain it to me step by step.
Thank you very much in advance,
~ Lukas

Comment: FYI JavaScript has references rather than pointers.

Comment: There's a decent explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/).

Answer (score 0):

> I  would highly appreciate if you could explain it to me step by step

Let's start with the state as it is after the values 1, 2 and 3 have been inserted:

```
 head                             tail
  ↓                                ↓
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │ next: ——————→ │ next:null│
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

When the `while` loop begins, we have introduced a few more references. Note how `second` got there via `first.next`, i.e. it references the same object as the `next` reference in the first object. Also, `this.tail` is set to its final value, so we don't have to think about that any more:

```
 first
 head
 tail            second
  ↓               ↓
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │ next: ——————→ │ next:null│
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

Now let's picture the effect of each assignment in the `while` loop:

### First iteration:

`const temp = second.next;` initialises a new reference, which equals the `next` reference in the object that is referenced by `second`:

```
 first
 head
 tail            second          temp
  ↓               ↓               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │ next: ——————→ │ next:null│
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

`second.next = first;` will redirect the `next` reference of the "second" object to its *preceding* node:

```
 first
 head
 tail            second          temp
  ↓               ↓               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │          │    │ next:null│
│          │ ←——— next     │    │          │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

Note how this detaches the third object from the list. Luckily we still have a reference to it via `temp`, otherwise we would have for ever lost it. And of course, this was the very reason to introduce the `temp` variable.

The next two statements will prepare the loop for its next round: the `first` and `second` references are updated to refer to the next node. This way the loop will be able to go from head to tail through the list.

`first = second;` results in this state:

```
 head            first
 tail            second          temp
  ↓               ↓               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │          │    │ next:null│
│          │ ←——— next     │    │          │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

And after `second = temp;` we have:

```
 head                            second
 tail            first           temp
  ↓               ↓               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │          │    │ next:null│
│          │ ←——— next     │    │          │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

### Second iteration:

`const temp = second.next;` initialises a new reference (the old `temp` only existed in the previous iteration). But as now `second` refers to the last node in the list, its `next` property is `null`, and so `temp` is `null`:

```
 head
 tail            first           second          temp: null
  ↓               ↓               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │          │    │ next:null│
│          │ ←——— next     │    │          │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

`second.next = first;` will redirect the `next` reference of the "second" object (which is the third object now) to its *preceding* node, as that is what `first` is referencing:

```
 head
 tail            first           second          temp: null
  ↓               ↓               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │          │    │          │
│          │ ←——— next     │ ←——— next     │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

The next two statements will prepare the loop for a potential next round: the `first` and `second` references are updated again to refer to the next node:

`first = second;` results in this state:

```
 head                            first
 tail                            second          temp: null
  ↓                               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │          │    │          │
│          │ ←——— next     │ ←——— next     │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

And after `second = temp;` we have:

```
 head                                            second: null
 tail                            first           temp: null
  ↓                               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next: ——————→ │          │    │          │
│          │ ←——— next     │ ←——— next     │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

Now the loop condition is false, so we exit the loop. At this moment we are sure that all `next` references are reversed, except the one in the first node, which should become `null`. And we also need to still adjust `head` so that it points to the last node. This is exactly what the remaining two assignments after the loop perform, and so we end up with:

```
                                 first           second: null
 tail                            head           (temp is out of scope)
  ↓                               ↓ 
┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌──────────┐
│ value: 1 │    │ value: 2 │    │ value: 3 │
│ next:null│ ←——— next     │ ←——— next     │
└──────────┘    └──────────┘    └──────────┘
```

Now the list has reversed, and both `head` and `tail` reference the nodes that they should reference.

### The algorithm

Concluding, this algorithm maintains three references that move along the list: `first`, `second` and `temp`. As long as they don't become `null` they always refer to 3 consecutive nodes in the list, and in each iteration they reference one node further down the list. This trio sticks together and walks from "left to right" in close collaboration.

Each node that get referenced by `second` will get its `next` reference updated so it refers to its preceding node. `temp` ensures that it is still possible to move along the remainder of the list, even though it is detached by this update of `next`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot!